# Relation between $k[x,y]/(y^3 - x^5)$ and its integral closure.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra

I am struggling with the following problem:

> Let $R = k[x,y]/(y^3 - x^5)$ and $S$ be its normalization. What is the dimension of the $k$-vector space $S/R$?

I started computing $S$, but most likely there are some dimension theory theorem that can help me to compute the dimension of $S/R$ without actually computing $S$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The title is quite misleading since one would think the answer would be $1$ if one only looks at the title.

Comment: Agreed, @MooS. Do you think my suggestion for the title is ok? If you can think of a better one, feel free to improve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can embed $R$ into $k[t]$ by means of $y\mapsto t^5$ and $x\mapsto t^3$.
We identify $R$ with $k[t^3,t^5]$ which is the span of $1$, $t^3$, $t^5$, $t^6$, $t^8$, $t^9$, $t^{10},\ldots$. The normalisation is $k[t]$, the integral closure of $R$. The missing monomials are $t$, $t^2$, $t^4$, $t^7$
so the dimension you seek is $4$.

Comment: Thanks @Lord Shark the Unknown!